# Customize function is not working

Tags: jquery

i was creating a customize function but it's not working

MY HTML

```
 <h3>REVEAL YOURSELF</h3>

  <p >
    REVEAL YOURSELF SOMEWHERE
  </p>
```

My jquery

```
 (function(){


    var object = {

        var p : $('p'),

        fadeSlideToggle: function(){
            $(this).animate({
                'height':'toggle',
                'opacity':'0'
            });
        }

    };

   $('h3').on('click', object.fadeSlideToggle);

})();
```

my function is working when i use

```
 (function(){

  $.fn.fadeSlideToggle = function(speed, fn){
        $(this).animate({
            'height':'toggle',
            'opacity':'0'
        },speed , fn)
    }

    $('h3').on('click', function(){500
        $('p').fadeSlideToggle();
    });


})();
```

why its not working through that way? please hrlp i'm new to jquery thanks :)

Comment: `var` in `var p` is incorrect where its situated; remove it - look in your error console

Answer (score 0):

You would, [indeed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31520714/customize-function-is-not-working#comment51002593_31520714), need to remove the keyword `var` in your object and have your code as such:

```
(function () {
     var object = {
         p: $('p'),
         fadeSlideToggle: function () {
             $(this).animate({
                 'height': 'toggle',
                     'opacity': '0'
             });
         }
     };

     $('h3').on('click', object.fadeSlideToggle);
 })();
```

Remove it and [your code will work](https://jsfiddle.net/oy0cn7v1/).